# How Probability of Detection can be calculated?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm a basic user, please mind my long question

I need to calculate the Probability of Detection:  POD = H/(H+M)

for 5 different categories; but I write only one to reduce confusion

light = [1,5)

I have two columns of data (in a CSV file), Observed and Estimated

I need a script to go through my data and categorize both observed and Estimated to "Light" when they are within the range [1,5).

Then, if Observed was light and the corresponding Estimated too, it is a hit (H)
if Observed was light but corresponding Estimated was not, it is a miss (M)

Then to sum H and sum M, and find POD = H / (H+M)

data sample:

```
observation, Estimation
0.2, 0.4
0.8, 0.8
1.0, 2.0
2.4, 0.9
3.1, 1.3
0.6, 0.5
1.2, 0.8
0.7, 0.9
2.3, 1.0
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I added a data sample to the post

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following is what the question asks for, the data format of `Light` is unclear, I will use a `list` of light categories.

```
POD <- function(O, E, Light){
  obs <- Light[1] <= O & O < Light[2]
  est <- Light[1] <= E & E < Light[2]
  H <- sum(obs & est)
  M <- sum(obs & !est)
  if(H + M > 0) H/(H + M) else 0
}


POD(O = df1[[1]], E = df1[[2]], Light = c(1, 5))
#[1] 0.6
```

Now a list of light categories.

```
LightCategories <- list(Cat1 = c(0, 0.5),
                        Cat2 = c(0.5, 1),
                        Cat3 = c(1, 5))

sapply(LightCategories, function(lc){
  POD(O = df1[[1]], E = df1[[2]], Light = lc)
})
#Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 
# 1.0  1.0  0.6
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = "
observation, Estimation
0.2, 0.4
0.8, 0.8
1.0, 2.0
2.4, 0.9
3.1, 1.3
0.6, 0.5
1.2, 0.8
0.7, 0.9
2.3, 1.0
")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it did not really solve my question.  It seems that I did not write the question in proper way. The category Light means light rainfall and is when the rainfall (which is the data sample) is within the range (1 to 5).  So, if my rainfall data under observation was within that range and also the corresponding estimation was also within the same range, this gives me a hit (H) and when observation is within the range but estimation is not, then it is a missing (M).  At the end, I need to count how many (H) and (M) I have to find POD which equals to H / H+M

Comment: @AliShawket You are still not clear, the function `POD` computes `H/(H + M)`. Do you also need the values of `H` and `M`?

Comment: Can we share any personal contacts that I can describe it in a better way please?

This is the first time I write question here and it seems I'm not doing it right at all.

Comment: @AliShawket My comment is clear: do you need the values of `H` and `M` or just the value of `POD` or all 3 values?

Comment: I want to only POD but I do not see it done in this script. 
I need the script to go to the data I have, check which observation is within the category, which mean the value of observation is within the range 1-5 

If yes, then to take that value of Observation and its corresponding estimation.  Then, check if the corresponding estimation is also within the same category, this is H but if not, it is M


At the end is POD, which will count how many H and how many M are there
and apply it in the POD = H/ H+M

Comment: @AliShawket But that's what the **function** does. And returns the value of `POD = H/(H + M)`.